# Encode MIPS BEQ instruction to Hex machine code manually

Tags: command, mips, machine-code, instruction-encoding

I'm trying to translate the following command to Hex:

```
beq $s1,$t3,label
```

It's also given that the command address is 0x1500, and the label address is 0x1000.

So far i know that beq equals 4(hex) and the binary values of the registers.

I know that at first I need to convert to binary and then to Hex, but i can't understand what to do with the label address. Do i need to divide it by 4 to get the value?

Answer (score 1):

`BEQ` opcode is `000100` (binary).
The instruction format for `BEQ` is:

```
OpCode|SR|DR|Offset
```

where

- OpCode(6 bits) is `000100`
- SR(5 bits) is `10001` for `$s1`
- DR(5bits) is `01011` for `$t3`
- offset(16 bits) is a 16 bits signed offset(shifted 2 times) assuming starting PC is the following instruction after the branch, should be (0x1000 - 0x1504)>>2 = -0x141, which written in A2 compliment is `1111111010111111`

You can now concatenate the bit fields and write them in hexadecimal if you wish:

`0001 0010 0010 1011 1111 1110 1011 1111` which is `0x122BFEBF`

*[edit: added explanation of how to compute the offset]*

To compute the offset you have to subtract the value of PC+4 (where PC stands for the address of the branch instruction) and the address of the target location. Then divide that address by 4 (or shift right two times). As the offset is encoded in A2 compliment, if the result of the operation is negative you have to apply A2's compliment to get the encoded value.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply. when I said that beq is 4, I meant that it's base conversion is 4 in hexa-decimal, which is in binary 0100.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how to calculate the immediate? I see that you took the label address and subtracted from it the PC instruction, then shifted right by 2. I'm sorry but I don't understand how you got '-0x141' , shouldn't it be( -0x504 / 4 )= -0x126 ? Thank you

Comment: @user3066968: I guess you subtracted in decimal rather than in hexadecimal. (1000-1504)/4 in decimal yields -126. (0x1000-0x1504)/4 in hexadecimal yields -0x141

Comment: Thank you for the heads-up, but I got the way, right?

Comment: @user3066968: Yes, i think you got it

Comment: Isn't -0x141 in binary is 0000 0001 0100 0001, and after A2 compliment is 1111 1110 1011 1110 ? maybe you were wrong at the last bit?

Comment: @user3066968: No. What you showed is A1 compliment (flip all bits). To apply A2 compliment you have to flip all the bits, then add 1. You forgot to add 1.